# Javascript initializtion code running multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html button element that has an attribute `onclick="onprof()"` which correctly gets called. The button is above the `<script>` element which is the last thing before the `</body>` tag. I set a breakpoint at the line that contains the code `var product = []` which gets activated on the page reload. I then hit the button which calls the function (I also have a breakpoint there) and that works fine, but then it goes to my original breakpoint and ends up breaking the code because it reinitializes the value of my variable `product`. Why is that Javascript being called again and how can I not get it to be called?

```
       <script type="text/javascript">

            var product = [];
            var temp=[]; 
            temp.push(1);
            temp.push("PET");
            product.push(temp);
            temp = [];
            temp2 = [];
            function onprof()
            {
               //alert(product);
                document.getElementById("typeform").innerHTML = product.toString();
            }
            function onprod()
            {

            }
            function onser()
            {

            }

        </script>
```

Comment: Is the `<button>` element part of a `<form>` by any chance? Try `onclick="onprof(); return false"`

Comment: It shouldn't call that code again. Only thing I can think of is that the page is reloading.

Comment: Why are you seeing that makes you think product is getting reinitialized?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal OP says they hit the breakpoint on the first line again in their debugger.

Comment: @Phil I feel like upvoting just because he knows how to use the debugger.

Comment: @Phil is that an attack on me? Do you think that is necessary?

Comment: @Barmar I know, right!

Comment: @Matthew Not sure what you mean by _"attack"_ or in reference to which comment. I was explaining to another user why it's clear that you're seeing the array re-initialised (ie, the debugger does not lie)

Comment: I was just wondering why you said "I feel like upvoting just because he knows how to use the debugger." It has a tone of "this guy has no clue what is going on."

Comment: @Matthew no, Barmar (not me) is praising you for actually using a debugger which is a rare occurrence on this site

Comment: Okay, sorry about being insensitive... I am arguing with people on other non-programming sites, and I think my attitude carried over to this. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a `form` which contains the `button`. On submit, forms reload the page. You can disable this behaviour by either:

1. Set the button type as `type="button"`. By default, it is submit.

or

2. Return `false` from your `onprof` function and use `onclick="return onprof()"`.

Comment: The type=button worked perfectly! Thank you. I tried just returning false too and it didn't seem to work, but maybe I wasn't doing something right, but it is all working now.

Comment: @Phil - Thanks for the edit. I am bit new to SO. Next time, I will try to clarify assumptions before posting answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Matthew - Checkout the edit from @Phil. You need to return from `onclick` too.